# Force.com IDE (Summer'14 release) - character set issue

Tags: force.com, ide, character-encoding

I have the following issue since using the latest version of Force.com IDE (31.0.0.201406301722) in our Summer'14 sandbox:

In the force.com IDE my code shows as follows:

String test = 'Zuständigkeit';

I save this code from the Force.com IDE into my Saleforce org.
But in the org the above shown code shows as follows:

String test = 'Zust�ndigkeit';

It seems that I have an issue with character sets (UTF-8)...

Is this a bug or what do I need to configure so that the characters are saved properly?

Thanks.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen that happen as well. For me, it's a bug. But Salesforce's support for the Force.com IDE is not 100%. They released it, some years ago, then abandoned it to the community, and these days they are releasing new versions. So I don't know if it's any use to file a case with Salesforce support.

For your information, I just use the Force.com IDE for downloading code and searching, because each Save action results in a deployment, with all unit tests being run, which takes way too long. Other editors that keep files on your own computer have the same problem.